# R less than returning true when it shouldn't

Tags: r

I'm trying to make a comparison in a data frame on multiple rows at once. Sometimes I'm getting true when I think I shouldn't...

```
df<-data.frame(x=c(1,4,3,4,6,7,4,7,4,2),y=c(8,5,3,7,8,4,1,3,0,2))
df[,c(1,2)]<c(4,5)
```

The example output is:

```
          x     y
 [1,]  TRUE FALSE
 [2,]  TRUE FALSE
 [3,]  TRUE  TRUE
 [4,]  TRUE FALSE
 [5,] FALSE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE  TRUE
 [7,] FALSE  TRUE
 [8,] FALSE  TRUE
 [9,] FALSE  TRUE
[10,]  TRUE  TRUE
```

- For row 1, that makes sense. 1 is less than 4, and 8 is not less than 5, so TRUE, FALSE.
- For row 3, that makes sense. 3 is less than 4, and 3 is less than 5, so both TRUE.
- For row 5, that makes sense. 6 is not less than 4, 8 is not less than 5, so both FALSE.

What's the deal with row 2? 4 is not less than 4, so why do we have a TRUE under "x"?

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Ah, yes, The output I gave above is what I get, rather than what I'd expect. I think the response from @akrun about using a list will do it!

Comment: Ok, thank you for the clarification.  Please check the solution below.  I misjudged it as expected

Comment: Cool, thanks for that. list() has indeed sorted the issue.

Comment: `list` will have each element act like a unit .  SO, the recycling occurs for each element separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can wrap in a `list` and it should work

```
df < list(4, 5)
```

-output

```
#          x     y
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE FALSE
# [3,]  TRUE  TRUE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE
# [6,] FALSE  TRUE
# [7,] FALSE  TRUE
# [8,] FALSE  TRUE
# [9,] FALSE  TRUE
#[10,]  TRUE  TRUE
```

---

Or another convenient option is `sweep`

```
sweep(df, 2, c(4, 5), `<`)
```

---

Or if we `rep`licate the vector to make the lengths same, then it would work as well

```
df < c(4, 5)[col(df)]
```

---

If it is a `vector`, the issue is that recycling occurs by column, so the first element 4 is compared to the first column first value, then 5 to second value of first column, and so on ...